# Gradle Connection timed out

Tags: android, gradle

after updating android studio 2.3 to 3.0 i got lots of errors so many work i done it but didn't work

Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>   Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom
>   Already seen doctype.
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Connection timed out: connect

gradle wrapper properties

```
#Mon Nov 06 17:20:27 IRST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

my gradle  (module app)

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "curlpagetutorial.example.com.mydd"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

New errors

Required by:
    project :app

> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>   Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom
>   Already seen doctype.
>
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>
> Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
>
> Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1.

I'm stuck here for long time please help me

Comment: Can you post your gradle-wrapper.properties file located in gradle directory?

Comment: @ViramP posted.

Comment: Have the same problem and after 2 days working on it , i did not find any solution

Answer (score 5):

Ihave had the same problem.
Finally I fixed it ussing an external gradle instalation. To make it you need to configure `File->Settings->Build,Execution and deployments->Gradle
Check -> Use local gradle distribution`
Select gradle home instalation.

If you are using an corporative connection, you also have to configure gradle proxy properties configuring or creating file `gradle.properties` in folder "`/Users/user/.gradle`":

```
#http proxy setup
systemProp.http.proxyHost=url
systemProp.http.proxyPort=port
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost

#https proxy setup
systemProp.https.proxyHost=url
systemProp.https.proxyPort=port
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

That's all!

Comment: I have tried many things to solve this problem but finally with your answer. Thanks a lot. What I have done is to edit gradle.properties file from the folder in .gradle ,not from the Android Studio ,

Answer (score 3):

Download gradle from:http://services.gradle.org/distributions/

choose the file such as gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip

Find your gradle directory in AndroidStudio 
    setting-->Build,Execution,Deployment -->Gradle

Unzip the file to "(your gradle path)\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew"